# In fractional knapsack implementation my solution is using always the same maximum index. How to sort my array in descending order?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, knapsack-problem, greedy

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import static java.lang.Integer.min;

public class FractionalKnapsack {
  // this method for calculating the maximum index
 
  public static int select_max_index(int []values,int []weights,int n){

        int index=0;
        double max=0;

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {

            if (weights[i] > 0 && (double) values[i] / (double) weights[i] > max) {

                max = (double) values[i] / (double) weights[i];
                index = i;
            }
        }

        return index;
    }

    private static double getOptimalValue(int  capacity, int  [] values, int[] weights,int n) {

        // fractional knapsack problem
        int i;
        int max_index=0;
        double value = 0.0000d;
        if (capacity == 0)
            return value;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            max_index = select_max_index(values,weights,n);// call the maximum index
            if (max_index >= 0) {
                int b = min(capacity, (weights[max_index]));
                value = value + b * ((double) values[max_index] / (double) weights[max_index]);
                weights[i] = (weights[max_index] - b);
                capacity = capacity - b;
            }
        }

        return value;
    }


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        int capacity = scanner.nextInt();
        int[] values = new int[n+2];
        int[] weights = new int[n+2];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            values[i] = scanner.nextInt();
            weights[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".0000"); // for getting the decimal point upto 4 digits
        df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);
        System.out.println(df.format(getOptimalValue(capacity, values, weights,n)));
    }
}
```

Inputs:

```
- 3 50
60 20
100 50
120 30
```

Correct output:

> 180.0000

my output:

> 200.0

My code is always using the same maximum index. I am beginner in programming

Answer (score 0):

To get it working you need to change:

1. Change `weights[i] = (weights[max_index] - b);` to `weights[max_index] = (weights[max_index] - b);` because you are modifying `max_index` weight, not another item's weight (**the index error**).
2. Initialization of `index` in `select_max_index` method (from `index=0` to `index=-1`). It is not necessary but would be good so `if (max_index >= 0)` makes sense.

Your algorithm's running time is O(n<sup>2</sup>). It is better to start the code sorting all items according to fractional knapsack criteria (greater `value/weight` comes first). You need to use a [custom comparator](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/arrays-sort-in-java-with-examples/). By proccessing the items in such order the time complexity will be O(n log n) which is lot better.